# Windows 8 shows up twice in Grub menu

Tags: grub2

I have a dual-boot installation with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8. I recently came across grub error and had to use boot-repair-disk. Now after fixing the system, Windows 8 appears to twice on sda1 and sda2. How can I remove the second one? I have checked and both of them boot the same.

Comment: Many users do not realize the 100MB Boot partition for Windows is vital, so they delete it. Boot-Repair copies Windows boot files into your main (c:) partition so you could still boot from that. Settings are not in any grub configuration files, but are found by os-prober which looks for those boot files. You can turn off os-prober and copy one boot stanza into 40_custom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: @vishalmullur I have the pb. I just created an issue to get help for that : https://github.com/campadrenalin/os-prober/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the grub configuration file at `/etc/grub/grub.cfg`, removing the offending entry and then enter `sudo update-grub`, however this can be a little difficult.

An alternate solution is to use GrubCustomizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then run the program `grub customizer` from the Dash.  It will display the menu nicely, allow you to delete an entry, and update grub for you

Comment: Nice workaround but unfortunatly the next time the linux-kernel is updated, the `update-grub` script will be run and then the `os-prober` will be called and the script `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft` will re-detect the Windows 8 BCD entries twice.